# I want the timer to begin counting down from 30 minutes immediately on page load and loop forever

Tags: javascript

For my site, I want the timer to begin counting down from 30 minutes immediately on page load and loop forever (until the user closes the page).

At the end of every 30 minute cycle, an alarm will go off. I have an mp3 file I will use. The alarm goes off, then the 30 minutes start again.

Comment: We need to see what you have tried already to give you a good suggestion/fix for your issue. We aren't here to code up what you need but instead help you figure out where an issue is. Please update this with code that you have tried and we can try and help you debug it.

Comment: Jay: Thanks for your advice...

Answer (score 1):

// I did it to solve the problem... Thanks all

```
window.loopingInterval = 30;
setInterval(loopingTimerMethod, 1000);


window.secondStart = 60;
window.loopingMinutes = loopingInterval - 1;
window.loopingSecond = secondStart;
function loopingStartTime(tim) {
    var i = tim - 1;
    return i;
}
function loopingTimerMethod()
{
    loopingSecond = loopingStartTime(loopingSecond);
    document.getElementById("timer-minutes").innerHTML = timeWithZero(loopingMinutes);
    document.getElementById("timer-second").innerHTML = timeWithZero(loopingSecond);
    if (loopingSecond == 0) {
        if (loopingMinutes == 0 && loopingSecond == 0) {
            var x = document.getElementById("myLoopingAudioPlayer");
            LoopingPlayAudio(x);
            window.loopingMinutes = loopingInterval;
        }


        loopingMinutes = loopingMinutes - 1;
        loopingSecond = secondStart;
    }

}

function LoopingPlayAudio(x) {
    x.play();
}

function LoopingPauseAudio(x) {
    x.pause();
}

function timeWithZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i
    }
    ;  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
/*END Timer Looping functionality*/
```